# Is there a practical limit to the number of files in a Swift container?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

A solution I work on stores files in OpenStack's Swift but the files are spread out into multiple containers. I have been told this is because the performance is awful after about a million files in a container. The only reference I could find is from a blog of 2010
[http://adrianotto.com/2010/09/openstack-os-is-great-for/](https://web.archive.org/web/20161008022640/http://adrianotto.com/2010/09/openstack-os-is-great-for/).

Since

1. I cannot find any other documentation about such a limitation/performance issue
2. It has been more than 10 years since the blog post

Is there **still** a limitation (or performance issue) to the number of objects in object storage in recent versions of OpenStack?

Comment: By the way, Stackoverflow is for programming. I suggest you ask system administration, operation, planning etc. questions on Serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/openstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was copied to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050701/is-there-a-practical-limit-to-the-number-of-files-in-a-swift-container), where I also moved my answer.